# Firebase Streaming from the REST API

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I'm using postman to do a get request for stream changing in my Firebase database but doesn't work.
The request take a long time with no response.

My firebase database:

[image: firebase database]

Postman request:

[image: postman request]

Answer (score 0):

Postman doesn't support Server Sent Event (as of May, 2021). The issue can be found [here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/6682).As an alternative, you can use other HTTP clients like curl to view the changes to the database in the real time.

```
curl -H 'Accept: text/event-stream' '<firebase-realtimedb-url>'
```